# Flutter how to fetch data when do tab switching

Tags: flutter

On Main page, I use `BottomNavigationBarItem` for tab navigation. On each tab, I have a widget that fetch the data in `initState`. I would like to know how to trigger the fetch data logic when tab is switching back to refresh the data. Thanks

- addition information

found out that I have 2 tabs which use same widgets but different parameters. then `initSate` is not triggered when do tab switching.

Comment: i can fix the problem after adding key to widget. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can add call http function inside build function. this will cause performance issue but you can use this function to make the performance better.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context){

WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
// call refresh function here
});
}
```